# one domain with equal IP for many subdomen

Tags: dns, subdomain, bind

I have many subdomain like this : sub1.domain.dev, sub2.domain.dev ... , subn.domain.dev 
I want to this all subdomains go to one ip.

i think , nedd to use "bind" dns, is it solution?

Comment: Please refer to [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for what questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: **software tools commonly used by programmers**

DNS bind not use in programming purpose? if it's not , sorry

Comment: @ user: Much more on topic over at http://serverfault.com, for instance.

Comment: No, it's not used for programming, it's used for network administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wildcard entry in the `domain.dev` zone file:

```
* IN A 1.2.3.4
```

This will set the IP for all names that don't appear explicitly in the zone file.